# XSLT format-number required to be done in such a way so that I can distinguish between 1.1 and 1.10 ?

Tags: xslt, weblogic12c

It was different value in old weblogic server env , with 12C upgraded env it is fetched as 1.1 same value.

```
<xsl:variable name="VALUE" select="TAG_NO"/>
```

Values of TAG_NO

```
<TAG_NO>1.1</TAG_NO>
<TAG_NO>1.10</TAG_NO>
```

how to re-write the above xsl variable so that it will pick the 1.1 as 1.1 and 1.10 and 1.10?

Comment: Your title mentions format-number, but your code doesn't use the function. The code that you *do* show will select the contents of `TAG_NO` *as is*: 1.1 as 1.1 and 1.10 as 1.10.

Comment: Actually I mentioned format-number because I tried writing many scenarios to control it using format-number.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following :

```
<xsl:variable name="VALUE" select="string(TAG_NO)"/>
```